# Amazon Web Service(Elastic Beanstalk) Multiple requests Health degraded in instance type t2.large

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to know why the below (attached image) error is arising when the user requests is greater than 10. The error is as shown below

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 1.5 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. 0.1 % of the requests to the ELB are  failing with HTTP 5xx

[image]

Comment: You should check logs on your backend instance(s) to find out why you have those 5xx errors.

Answer (score 0):

Does your instance stay in "Degraded" status, or does it quickly change back to "Ok"?

I see infrequent and short-lived occurrences of "Degraded" status, though I'm not sure if your setup is like ours. Here's what I've been able to learn in case it helps.

When I look in my logs, I don't see **any** HTTP 5xx status codes. What I do see, however, are occasional 499s. Additionally, every time a 499 is logged, it's from a Googlebot request.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), 499 is an nginx code that is logged "when the client has closed the request before the server could send a response", but "These are only used for logging purposes, no actual response is sent with these codes."

I suspect that the ELB is interpreting this situation as a 5xx failure, triggering the sporadic "Degraded" health. Since it doesn't appear to be affecting actual users, though, I haven't spent any more time investigating.